# How to delete audio input option in system preferences macOS

Tags: audio, thunderbolt, big-sur, microphone, voice-dictation

I've got a problem:
Since I am using my new Elgato Thunderbolt 3 Pro dock, the macOS dictation won't work anymore. It seems like macOS won't use the internal microphone for dictation. I changed the audio input to the internal microphone (and that one is working!). I can use Siri and record audio, but I cannot use dictation.

I am running macOS 11.1.

Any ideas?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

Go to System preferences → Accessibility → Voice Control.
There you can choose the desired audio input. Setting it for voice control sets it for dictation as well.
You do not have to turn on voice control.

[image]